# Preserving JRuby gems between upgrades

Tags: jruby, rubygems

When installing one of JRuby's frequent upgrades, I need to re-install my gems, as they normally reside in the jruby install directory.

I know it doesn't have to be this way.  Could someone post some instructions or point to a web page on how to avoid this?

Keep in mind, I'm not wanting to share gems with a C-Ruby install.  Just share between JRuby installs.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add directory tree `<your preferred location>/jrubygems/lib/ruby/gems/1.8`
2. Add directory tree `<your preferred location>/lib/ruby`
3. Add directory tree `<your preferred location>/lib/site_ruby/1.8`

Add to your .bashrc:

`export GEM_HOME=<your preferred location>/jrubygems/lib/ruby/gems/1.8`

`export RUBYLIB=<your preferred location>/lib/ruby:<your preferred location>/lib/site_ruby/1.8`